# WordPress color picker is not working

Tags: wordpress, colors, themes, picker

The color picker is still into the theme Customizing options but when i change color of links and buttons, the color is not change of buttons and links. Please help Thanks for your valuable answers.

```
//Customize Appearance Options

function myTheme_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
```

//setting for link color

```
    $wp_customize->add_setting('mtm_link_color', array(
        'default' => '#006ec3',
        'transport' => 'refresh',
    ));
```

//setting for Button color

```
    $wp_customize->add_setting('mtm_btn_color', array(
        'default' => '#006ec3',
        'transport' => 'refresh',
    ));
```

//Section for standard colors

```
    $wp_customize->add_section('mtm_standard_colors', array(
        'title' => __('Standard Colors', 'MyTheme'),
        'priority' => 30,
    ));
```

//Adding control for links color picker

```
    $wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Color_Control($wp_customize,'mtm_link_color_control', array(
        'label' => __('Link Color', 'MyTheme'),
        'section' => 'mtm_standard_colors',
        'settings' => 'mtm_link_color',

    ) ) );
```

//Adding control for buttons color picker

```
    $wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Color_Control($wp_customize,'mtm_btn_color_control', array(
     'label' => __('Button Color', 'MyTheme'),
     'section' => 'mtm_standard_colors',
     'settings' => 'mtm_btn_color',

 ) ) );

}

add_action('customize_register', 'myTheme_customize_register');


//Output Customize CSS

function myTheme_customize_css() { ?>
    <style type="text/css">

             a:link,
       a:visited
             {
                 color:<?php echo get_theme_mod('mtm_link_color'); ?> ;
             }

             .site-header nav ul li.current-menu-item a:link,
             .site-header nav ul li.current-menu-item a:visited{
                 background-color: <?php echo get_theme_mod('mtm_link_color'); ?> ;
             }

       div.search #searchsubmit{
                  background-color: <?php echo get_theme_mod('mtm_btn_color'); ?> ;
             }

    </style>
<?php }
add_action('wp_haed', 'myTheme_customize_css');
```

Comment: can you tell us if you are getting any error ?

Comment: For start : `add_action('wp_head', 'myTheme_customize_css');`

Comment: Thanks for reply.... No, i'm not getting any error...and also have color picker tabs in theme's customize options but not able to change color

Comment: @DejoDekic Thank you very much...it's a spelling mistake.Now everything is cool